# Modify variables within Python through a button in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have an application that at a certain point needs to **check if a variable within its Python code has one value or another**, and also requires a **button capable of changing that variable** from one value to another to also **save that information in a text file and that the variable loads it the next time the application is started**.

Here I prepared a small program to exemplify what I am looking for:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size=(200,200)

data=open('data.txt','r') #Let's say there is a text file called "data" that contains the number 0

Builder.load_string("""
<Screen>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size:root.width,root.height
        Label:
            text:'Switch On' if app.var==1 else 'Switch Off' #Initially then the label should say "Switch Off"
        Button:
            text:'Switcher'
            on_release: #Change app.var from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0
""")

class Screen(Widget):
    pass

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        self.var=data.read()
        #Save the changes made by the Button 
        return Screen()

if __name__=='__main__':
    App().run()
```

How can I do this or something **similar**? A better and simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a function and bind it to a button. The [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html) can really help you here! you can bind your function using `my_button.bind(on_press=on_button_click)` where:

```
def on_button_click():
    this.my_var += 1
```

Let me know if you think the documentation is unclear!